# How does one change a range of commits to have happened on another branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

My assumption is that the solution is simple, but I cannot find any examples that clearly address my problem. I seek guidance on the following:

I currently have a history like:

```
A - - - C - - - - - F            Master
  \       \           \
    B - - - D - E - - - G - H    Topic
```

`D`, `E`, `G`, and `H` should have all happened on `Master`. The only differences at this point should be commit `B`. So it should look like:

```
A - - - C - D - E - F - G - H    Master
  \
    B                            Topic
```

Or even better yet:

```
A - C - D - E - F - G - H        Master
                          \
                            B    Topic
```

... but I have no idea how to accomplish that either.

It doesn't seem that I can merge `D`, `E`, `G`, and `H` all at once. I keep ending up with `B` in `Master`.

I believe I could cherry-pick them, but that seems to present future problems. What is the best solution?

Comment: You can use interactive rebase ( `git rebase -i` ) to move the commits onto Master. Alternatively, if you've already ended up with all of them on Master, you can force the `master` branch to the parent of B (H) and force `topic` to `B` using `git branch -f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have pushed these branches to any remote repo, It's not a good idea to rewrite past history. If you have pushed, I'd avoid rewriting by doing this:

1. Start on `Master`'s `F` HEAD.
2. Cherry-pick `D`, `E`, `G` and `H` on `Master`.
3. Checkout `Topic` and merge from `Master`.

If you do this, you will have:

```
A - - - C - - - - - F - - - - - D' - E' - G' - H'-       Master
  \       \           \                            \
    B - - - D - E - - - G - H - - - - - - - - - - - -    Topic
```

The history won't look super-neat, but you'll have every bit of code in the branch you want.

---

If you really want to rewrite history because this is just local to you or you don't care about messing with other people who may be pulling from your repo, then:

1. Roll back master to `C` (note down `F`'s hash before rolling back).
2. Cherry-pick `D`, `E`, `F`, `G` and `H` on `Master`.
3. Branch `Topic2` from `Master`'s `H` head.
4. Cherry-pick `B` on `Topic2`.
5. Delete `Topic`, rename `Topic2` to `Topic`.

And you get:

```
A - C - D - E - F - G - H        Master
                          \
                            B    Topic
```

Comment: While both Ricardo and torek's answers are correct, this is the one that I worked from, and, although brief, it gave the necessary information. Please see torek's explanation for much greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the drawings are accurate, "you can't get there from here".  (You may be able to get close enough though.)  Specifically, the stumbling block is commit `F`.

The commit you labeled `F` that's currently on branch `Master` has commit `C` as its parent.

In the new desired graphs, the commit labeled `F` has commit `E` as its parent.

Since a commit is a cryptographic checksum of all of its contents (its tree, message, author/committer and time-stamps, and—here's the problem—all its parent IDs as well), any new "F-like" commit that has `E` as its parent is necessarily a *different* commit.

The "better yet" graph shows commit `B` with `H` as its parent, so again this is different from the "existing" graph.  So this has the same problem as `F` (with the same potential solution).

The branch-labels `Master` and `Topic` also have to change.  Neither change will be a "fast-forward" (in git terminology).

The question you need to answer here is: who else besides yourself has access to this repository or a copy of this repository, and are they (all such accessors) willing to do what it takes to handle a non-fast-forward branch-label change?

If the answer is "no one else has such access", or "they are all willing to do what it takes", you're fine.  If not, you'll need another approach.  Let's assume the best, for now.

You still can't quite get there from here, because we need to make a change to what you've drawn as commit `F`, and you can never change a commit.  You can't change `D` and `E` either, and while you don't need to change `H` directly, you need to change `G`—it currently has two parents—and changes "bubble through": we'll see why in a moment, with parent-IDs changing.

What you need to do is to *copy* the commits to new, slightly-different versions.  We'll copy commit `D` to a version that omits any changes from `B` and has only `C` as its parent.  Let's call this copy `D'`, to indicate that it's "a lot like `D`, but not quite the same".

Then, we'll copy `E` to a version that has the same changes as the old `D`-to-`E`, but lists `D'` as its parent.

Next, we'll find what happened between `C` and `F` and make those same changes to what's in `E'` and commit that as `F'`, with the same message, etc., as in the original `F`.

Last, we want the changes that occurred between `F` and `G` (and *not* those from `E` to `G`), applied to `F'`, and committed as `G'` with the same message, etc., as in `G`; and then we take the changes from `G` to `H`, apply them to `G'`, and commit as `H'`.

The result looks like this (we're not yet quite to your less-preferred alternative):

```
A---C---D'--E'--F'--G'--H'   <-- Master
 \    \
  \    \-----F   [old Master was here]
   \    \     \
    B----D--E--G--H   <-- Topic
```

Now to make `Topic` end at `B`, we simply have to re-point it to commit `B`.  The remaining commits will still be in the repository, but with no labels pointing to them (other than the reflogs):

```
A---C---D'--E'--F'--G'--H'   <-- Master
 \    \
  \    \-----F
   \    \     \
    B----D--E--G--H
     `.......................<-- Topic
```

We now have what you wanted as your less-preferred alternative.

To obtain your preferred alternative, we now simply need to rebase `B` onto `Master`.  This copies `B` to a new commit `B'` that has the same changes as the old `A`-to-`B` (omitting any that are no longer needed due to being in `C` through `H`), but has `H'` as its parent.  Redrawing the graph, leaving out all the no-longer-labeled commits, gives:

```
A---C---D'--E'--F'--G'--H'   <-- Master
                         \
                          B' <-- Topic
```

As for the mechanics of actually copying commits about, well, the work-horse that does this is `git cherry-pick`.  Using `git rebase -i` (without `-p`), you can make git do a series of cherry-picks.  There is a bit of a stumbling block with the merge commits, though.  An interactive rebase can omit trivial merges but for more complex merges, you need to supply the `-m` argument to `git cherry-pick` to tell it which "side" of the merge to pick from.

So, from the existing starting point, here's how I would do it (there are many possible methods):

```
git checkout -b temp Master^  # make new "temp" branch pointing to commit C
git cherry-pick -m 2 Topic~3  # get C->D changes, make D'
git cherry-pick Topic~2       # get D->E changes, make E'
git cherry-pick Master        # get C->F changes, make F'
git cherry-pick -m 2 Topic~1  # get F->G changes, make G'
git cherry-pick Topic         # get G->H changes, make H'
```

Along the way, or at the end, use `git show` on each commit to make sure you got what you wanted (and that I have the `-m` argument correct here).

If all went well, move branch `Master` to match the new `temp`:

```
git checkout master; git reset --hard temp # reset Master to equal temp
git branch -d temp             # and delete temp, no longer needed
```

and now you can reset and rebase `Topic`:

```
git checkout Topic; git reset --hard HEAD~4 # reset to point to B
git rebase Master              # copy B to B' and reset to B'
```

(Slightly more advanced trick: instead of `git checkout -b temp`, just `git checkout` and use the detached HEAD mode to construct the desired new `Master`, then move it manually.  That's how the interactive rebase shell script does it.  But it's more confusing, so probably better to be explicit, as above.)

---

If you have other people using these branches, they must recover from your "non-fast-forward" changes by doing their own resets and/or rebases.  The method is describe as "recovering from an upstream rebase" in the [git rebase documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, torek. I learned a lot from your help. I'm going to mark Ricardo's because it was so succinct that I started working on his answer before yours was posted, so I stuck to it. Both would seemingly work similarly (actually they may be the same solution). If I have made a mistake using Ricardo's method, please let us know. Again thank you for explaining in such detail. This is the first time I've felt conflicted because both answers came immediately and were correct.

Comment: Ricardo's method is fine too.  Rolling `Master` back to commit `C` is the same, in the end, as creating a new temp branch at commit `C`, and removes the need to re-shuffle the branches later.  (It does rely on the reflogs to keep the intermediate commits safe from garbage collection during the cherry picking process.)  As usual with git, there's more than one way to do things.